Salesforce Lightning Component disappearing after page refresh
I have a lightning component in my Experience Cloud site that disappears if the page is refreshed. The only way I can get it to reappear is if I log out and back into the site or if I make a modification to the component itself in developer console. This can be any modification such as deleting a line of code and simply adding it back and saving. Is there anything I can do to prevent the component from disappearing?



Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read How to Ask and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have done and where you are stuck. Are errors reported on the page? Have you looked at the browser console output when the component disappears? Can you include your component's code so we can look for obvious mistakes?

Including code as text is much preferred over including screenshots. Long lines can render the rest of the text illegible, and fixing a simple mistake would mean people are forced to type out enough surrounding context for the fix to make sense (as opposed to being able to copy/paste it, then just do enough typing to fix the mistake). The harder it is / more obstacles there are, the fewer people you'll find willing to help. Addressing the other points that Phil W brought up would also be helpful.

Sure, I can include the code. I'm quite certain it's a cache issue. If I right click > inspect > network > select “disable cache” it seems to load for me after each reload. Do you know if there's something I can do to solve for that?
